# Stitch/join sound data in flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am wondering if any one can point me in the right direction.

I have a number of sound objects. I am wondering if there is any way I can pull out the byte arrays and stitch them together into as one bytearray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is very much possible, take a look at [Sound.extract()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29) and [SampleDataEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#event%3asampleData).

Comment: thanks, so it's a case of extracting and joining the bytearrays together in one sound object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful sound library StandingWave 3 by Max Lord and Joe Berkovitz 
http://maxl0rd.github.com/standingwave3
MIT license

You can stitch sounds together and play the result sound easily.